# find out the maximum row from each 100 iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have create a mat file:

```
S = load abc.mat

S = data1: [81x30 double]
    data2: [59x28 double]
    data3: [20x28 double]
```

after loading this mat file, then i use this mat file to run some code and the result display as below in the command window

```
disp([Ball Trial A B C D])

30.0000    1.0000    0.4498    0.3652    0.4601    0.3777

30.0000    2.0000    0.5745    0.5006    0.5671    0.4940

...

30.0000   99.0000    0.5209    0.4420    0.5112    0.4311

30.0000  100.0000    0.4078    0.4142    0.3974    0.4060

35.0000    1.0000    0.4303    0.3563    0.4083    0.3356

35.0000    2.0000    0.5239    0.4469    0.5174    0.4396

...

35.0000   99.0000    0.6009    0.5442    0.5985    0.5410

35.0000  100.0000    0.5327    0.4756    0.5037    0.4503

...

100.0000   99.0000    0.3015    0.3273    0.3027    0.3287

100.0000  100.0000    0.4416    0.3960    0.4533    0.4088
```

The fist column is from ball 30 to ball 100 (30:5:100), the 2nd column is the 100 iteration, then the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th is the result for A, B, C, D

```
[c t] = max(max(C.'));% variable c is the max of C in each ball (index) t.
```

i would like to plot a line graph which include max c in each index (ball)..where x-axis is t (ball 30 to 100) and y-axis is the variable c...may i know how to draw?

and also display out the row of maximum c on each index (ball) in a .txt file...

result: def.txt

```
30.000 23.000 0.23 0.45 0.76 0.32

35.000 19.000 0.43 0.67 0.23 0.54

...

100.000 43.000 0.54 0.11 0.54 0.99
```

Does anyone can help me plot the graph and get the def.txt? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html).

```
%# data is the content of abc.mat
load('abc.mat')

%# find x, corresponding indices into y
[x,~,yIdx] = unique(data(:,1));

%# in each column, collect the maximum for each yIdx
y = zeros(length(x),4);
for col=1:4
    y(:,col) = accumarray(yIdx,data(:,col+2),[],@max);
end

%# plot
ph=plot(x,y);
set(ph,{'DisplayName'},{'A';'B';'C';'D'})
legend()

%# save result to file
dlmwrite('def.txt', [x y])
```

Comment: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> testing at 10
    y(:,col) = accumarray(yIdx,S(:,col+2),[],@max);

Comment: @noob: instead of `S` use `data` where `data = [Ball Trial A B C D];`